# How can I add a line break in the email body after pasting each chart?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the email message to have the charts pasted below each other, currently they are just pasted in a series and it looks very messy.
How can I add a line break in the email body after pasting each chart? I've tried using 
, and pasting blank cells but it either doesn't work or I'm not using it properly.

Many Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Dim weekno As Long
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim wrdEdit

ActiveSheet.Select
weekno = Range("C2").Value

'get running Outlook Application
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'create a new email
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'set the subject and recipient
oMail.Subject = "Execution and Unavailability Report for Week " & weekno
oMail.To = ""
'show it
oMail.Display
'change to HTML
oMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
'get the word editor
Set wrdEdit = oApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor


ActiveSheet.Range("A50").Select
Selection.Copy
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.Range("A51").Select
Selection.Copy
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.Range("A52").Select
Selection.Copy
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.Range("A53").Select
Selection.Copy
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste


    Sheets("ACT Statistics").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
 wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste

    Sheets("ATD Statistics").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

'paste it into the email
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste


'use oMail.Send to autosend
'release objects
Set wrdEdit = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Although it is almost too ugly for me to paste here...

```
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Paste
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
wrdEdit.Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
```